# Redundancy of many "many to many"

Tags: sql-server, database-design, many-to-many

I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzEw9.png) database scheme that represents a simple forum. In forum i need to add an access by roles to sections/topics/posts. My solution is [create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJLsH.png) "many to many" tables for every entity that's need to be restricted. **Is better way to do it without unnecessary redundancy?**

Comment: The way to solve Many:many is with a bridging table like you are doing.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained. Please do not include unnecessary stuff in your question. Eg most of the content of those images.

Comment: What redundancy? What is "redundancy"? PS If you don't know how to answer this post then you don't need to worry about things like "redundancy" until you learn enough about design to discuss what it is let alone what to do about it. Learn basics of good design. PS (Obviously) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: My two cents: I question logic in having security control at a post level as it is too granular; how would you assign roles to each post?. `Posts_Roles` and even `Topics_Roles` are IMO overkill. Otherwise, you are on the right track.

Comment: Have a look on the chapter "Data access security" in my book ["Programming with databases"](https://www.amazon.com/dp/2956300806)